# How to imitate CustomListAdapter using variable <objects>

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to implement a customlistadapter for a small project of mine. I basically want ask java to use the appropriate class to inflate the view. I have here first:

```
public class slide {

    public class video {
        VideoView videoOfTheDay;

        //Purpose of this constructor
        public video(VideoView videoOfTheDay) {
            this.videoOfTheDay = videoOfTheDay;
        }

        public VideoView getVideoOfTheDay() {
            return videoOfTheDay;
        }

    }

    public class blog {
        ImageView imageOfTheDay;
        TextView messageOfTheDay;

        public blog(ImageView imageOfTheDay, TextView messageOfTheDay) {
            this.imageOfTheDay = imageOfTheDay;
            this.messageOfTheDay = messageOfTheDay;
        }

        public ImageView getImageOfTheDay() {
            return imageOfTheDay;
        }

        public TextView getMessageOfTheDay() {
            return messageOfTheDay;
        }
    }

    public class advertisement {
        ImageView ImageViewAd1;
        ImageView ImageViewAd2;

        public advertisement(ImageView imageViewAd1, ImageView imageViewAd2) {
            this.ImageViewAd1 = imageViewAd1;
            this.ImageViewAd2 = imageViewAd2;
        }

        public ImageView getImageViewAd1() {
            return ImageViewAd1;
        }

        public ImageView getImageViewAd2() {
            return ImageViewAd2;
        }
    }
}`
```

I have listed all the classes within a superclass slide because I wasn't able to accomplish no errors without them being grouped. From there I went to ask Java to look within itself and determine the appropriate class to use to populate the element:

```
class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private ArrayList<slide> customVariableDisplay;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<slide>customVariableDisplay) {
            this.customVariableDisplay = customVariableDisplay;
            layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return customVariableDisplay.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return customVariableDisplay.get(position);
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        // If the element of the slide is a video -- then the getView will return...
        if(slide==slide.video){
            public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.act_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.slide.video = (VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.videolayout);
                }
            else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
                holder.video.setVideoResource(customVariableDisplay.get(position).getVideoOfTheDay());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
        // If the element is a 'blog' then --- then the getView will return...
        else if(slide==slide.blog){
            public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
            ViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.act_layout, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.slide.blog.message = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.messageInLayout);
                holder.slide.blog.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageInLayout);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }
                //Can write to getClass() for either?
                //Ex: holder.(setImageResource(cVD) || setText(cVD)).getClass ??
                holder.image.setImageResource(customVariableDisplay.get(position).getImageofTheDay());
                holder.message.setText(customVariableDisplay.get(position).getMessageOfTheDay());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
        //Else if the element of the slide is an 'advertisement' then the getView will return...
        else if (slide==slide.advertisement){
            public View getView ( int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                ViewHolder holder;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.act_layout, null);
                    holder = new ViewHolder();
                    holder.slide.advertisement.imagead1 = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAdOneInAdvertisementLayout);
                    holder.slide.blog.image = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageAdTwoInAdvertismentLayout);
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }
                else {
                    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.imagead1.setImageResource(customVariableDisplay.get(position).getImageViewAd1());
                holder.imagead2.setImageResource(customVariableDisplay.get(position).getImageViewAd2());
            }
            return convertView;
        }
        else{
            //Throw a final View exception for unprecedented errors!!
        }
    }
}`
```

I am stuck with what to a way to ask Java what class is it inside the if statements. // If this slide comprises the class blog... etc. ANY HELP APPRECIATED! THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

You can declare one variable slideType in your adapter and pass it to your adapter constructor and based on that value inflate your layout in `onBindViewHolder()`, `onCreateViewHolder()`

```
int slideType;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<slide>customVariableDisplay, int slideType) {
  this.slideType = slideType;
}
```

and also define three separate method in your adapter to pass your list so that you can bind your data.

Answer (score 0):

Does this `ListView` show a mix of video, blog etc.. if yes then you need use below checking.

```
if(null != slide.video){
    // add code for video
  }
else if(null != slide.blog){
    // add code for blog
  }
else if (null != slide.advertisement){
    // add code for advertisement
  }
```

Also you need to set null for blog and advertisement in slide object or don't initialize them in case the item you want to show is video